# How can I add a user to the database (kept in memory) / no database/storage back-end is available

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, storage, in-memory-database

In an online test I received the following instructions: Add a user to the database **(kept in memory)**. The request body is JSON shaped, as follows:

```
{
  "id": "aabbbccddeeefff",
  "name": "User One",
  "hobbies": [ "swim", "sing", "workout" ]
}
```

(Added users should be **kept in memory; no database/storage back-end is available**.)

And in code editor they just put:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Your code starts here. Placeholders for .get and .post are provided for
//  your convenience.

app.post('/users', function(req, res) {

});

app.get('/users/search', function(req, res) {

});

app.listen(process.env.HTTP_PORT || 3000);
```

It does not allow me to import more libraries (mongoose, fs,etc) 
Example: If I import: 
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');` the console shows `Cannot find module 'mongoose'`.

***Any idea how you should address the problem.***
I don't understand how to add a new user to a database if I can't define the collection model (I don't have mongoosee)

**Any suggestion is welcome.**

Comment: The point of the test is for you to figure out how to solve the problem, so that your understanding of the materials can be evaluated. You've been given the necessary information. You may need to go back and review your lessons or notes.

Comment: Create a variable, either an array, map, object or whatever. Name it "database" and store users in it. Or write a module with CRUD functions that store, modify or remove data that you store in an array, map, object - you get the idea - and name the module "database".

Comment: Ken White, thank you, but my question is about the term "kept in memory; no database / storage back-end is available".

I learned to do CRUDs with a database, but I had never heard this term "kept in memory / no database" and I have already searched the internet a lot without examples to help me understand it better.

Comment: The "model" for data you store can be as simple as the shape of the JSON they give you. No need to use any specific database framework like Mongoose, nor is there any need to have a specific Model class. The clue by @ToddR is pointing you to think about the fact that a global (module-level) variable - even a simple array - can serve as a container for your records, and so can serve as a simple "database". good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comments @ToddR and @Myk Willis.
I tried something like that. You really helped me too much by clarifying these doubts. 
`var users=[];

app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    console.log('POST');
     if(!req.body){
            res.status(400).send({ success: false });
     }else{
            let user = req.body;
            users.push(user);
            console.log('users',users);
            res.status(201).send({ success: true });
     }
});`

Comment: Could you do this? I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the data in variables (likely global).

Try to NOT think about all the things that a real database provides; like persistence. You may have to assume that the test cases will all use the same memory when run, which again is not normal. It would be fair for them to share those kinds of details.

It is easy to see why this would confuse someone; as this is something you would NEVER do in any REAL life coding situation other than these creative interview questions. I don't believe you are even allowed to use files either. With these online coding assessments you REALLY have to think outside the box, which slows you down.

It would have been easy for them to spin up a container alongside the container that runs the tests to make the situation less awkward. Also, they don't ask questions like these when practicing on their site. So surprise!